# Maintain MongoDB validation rules with multiple validation commands

Tags: mongodb, validation

I would like to update the validation rules on a database individually.

Take for example the following collection from this [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/):

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
   { validator: { phone: { $type: "string" } }
} )
```

We can then look at the validation rules (truncated for conciseness):

```
db.getCollectionInfos({name:"contacts"})

        "validator" : {
            "phone" : {
                "$type" : "string"
            }
        }
```

If I decide to to add a new validation:

```
db.runCommand( {
   collMod: "contacts",
   validator: { email: { $exists: true } }
} )
```

The original validation is gone:

```
db.getCollectionInfos({name:"contacts"})

        "validator" : {
            "email" : {
                "$exists" : true
            }
        },
```

Is it possible to maintain validation across multiple queries? The use case for this is that there may be many validation rules applied to a collection over time, and it seems inefficient to reapply all validations each time. Or perhaps I am thinking about this the wrong way?